# App already in app store - generated new certificate for APN. Re upload?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I already uploaded an app to appstore and is downloadable.

**Developer Portal**

We realized that Push notifications for the Provisioning Profile was disabled.

So, we enabled it from Identifiers.

Then, under Provisioning Profile the certificate became invalid - so we had to regenerate it and the new certificate has Push Notifications Enabled under Enabled Services.

The question now, the App is already in Appstore.

1) Do we need to re-upload the app to appstore?

2) What about the Push Notification certificate that we generated recently (before Enabling the service) - do we need to regenerate it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you'll need to upload a new build. This is because the current ipa won't be signed with a distribution profile that enables push. Therefore, it won't work.

2) Regenerating a provisioning profile won't affect your push certificate. This is because the certificate is tied to your app id, not any specific provisioning profile. As long as you haven't removed / tampered with the app id, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to regenerate the iOS certificates for the "iOS Distribution" and "App Push Services"? Or; regenerating the Provisioning Profile should suffice? Note that I enabled the Push Notifications from "Identifiers" and haven't regenerated any certificate, just the Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Just regenerating the distribution profile will be fine, as long as you had a working push certificate before. Make sure you test it before you upload this time!

Comment: I tested the APN against apple server, I get error 8 which is bad token but the certificate works perfectly. Reading this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927351/app-already-in-app-store-generated-new-certificate-for-apn-re-upload it seems that all I need to do is regenerate the (now invalid) provisioning profile (which became valid with APN enabled) - and build the ios app signed with the provisioning profile and distribution certificate. But, why regenerate the distribution certificate? Regenerating the provisioning profile shouldn't be enough?

Comment: So I never said distribution certificate :P The provisioning profile you use to sign apps for the app store is called a distribution profile. So as I said earlier, all you have to do is regenerate that profile and it should all work.